# Quantum computer: What are the carriers of information and what is the spatial arrangement of the individual information carriers?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-computer

I assume that the carriers of the information bits are electrons with their spin or magnetic dipoles.
Are there other bit carriers for quantum computers?

And, how are these bits arranged spatially in relation to each other?

Comment: There are many other physical platforms for quantum computing, each with their own way of carrying the information: trapped ion quantum computing, linear optical quantum computing, quantum computing using superconducting circuits, etc

Comment: Related questions: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/74/15820 https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1580/15820 and answers: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/1184/15820 https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/1395/15820

Comment: @QuantumMechanic For example ion traps: What are the carriers of the information in detail and what is the spatial arrangment  of the carriers inside the ion? May you see what I‘m curoius of?

Comment: In ion traps, the information is "in what energy level is the electron in the ion excited?" There are often two levels of interest, so that gives us a qubit. If we have $N$ ions in the same trap, we can have $N$ qubits. One could consider these as $N$ qubits each in a different spatial position (typically along a line in one dimension), or one could consider the normal modes of the motion of the set of $N$ qubits (phonons) and look at those as carrying information

Comment: Any quantum system that can be in two distinguishable states and fullfil DiVincenzo's criteria (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DiVincenzo%27s_criteria) can be used as a base for quatum computer.